# Who was Ali-Ibn-Mahziar al-Ahvazi (al-Ahwazi)?

Tags: shiism, islamic-scholar, shrine

َAs far as I know, there is the shrine (tomb) of a person whose name is considered as Ali-ibn-Mahziar-al-Ahvazi (علی بن مهزیار الاهوازی) in Ahvaz (Ahwaz) (the capital of Khuzestan province (Iran)). Seemingly he is as a famous Faghih (the jurist) and also a narrator of traditions. I was wondering who he was exactly and which Imam he was contemporary with.

Answer (score 1):

**Ali ibn Mahziar Ahvazi (علی بن مهزیار الاهوازی):**

He was one of devotees (or actually companions) of Imam Mohammad al Taqi (Javad) (p.b.u.h.),
Imam Hadi and Imam Hasan Askari (peace be upon them)...

> Ali ebne mahziar ahvazi (the 9th century ) was famous shiah religious
> jurisprudent , religious narrator and savant , he was one of devotees
> of Imam Javad (p.b.u.h.) , Imam Hadi (p.b.u.h.) And Imam Hasn Askari
> (p.b.u.h.) and learned Islamic jurisprudences of them and in some
> areas especially Ahvaz he was their agent , shiah savants accepted his
> religious narrates about holy Imams (p.b.u.h.) with complete
> confidence .
>
> Ali ebne mahziar was of Doraq (Shadegan) people  ,later
> he resided in Ahvaz . nevertheless he was born in Hendijan ( hendian)
> but because Hendijan was Doraq  city subarea he was introduced as
> Doraq resident . his father was Christian But at adolescence along
> with his father turned into Muslim . according with some stories he
> died at Imam Hasn Askari (p.b.u.h.) time . according with historical
> narratives , when  Abasi caliph mamoon commanded to transfer Imam Reza
> ( p.b.u.h.) to Khorasn from Madineh,  The Imam entered Ahvaz at year
> 822 and stayed at this city , few days , after that on Imam  (
> p.b.u.h.) settlement location , a mosque as Masjed Alreza  was built
> which Ali ebne mahziar had willed that his body buried in mentioned
> mosque , there is a salon , at west part adjoining to the grave,
> probably it is the mosque that mentioned before .

---

**Source:**

[www.english.ahvaz.ir](http://english.ahvaz.ir/Default.aspx?tabid=2658)